# Java Get Size of Font

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jpanel, jtextarea

I have `JFrame` with a `JTextArea` inside of it.

```
Font font = new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14);
textarea.setFont(font);
```

Since the font is monospaced, all characters are the same width and height.

I'd like to know what this width and height is in pixels.

For this, I could use `font.getStringBounds` but I have no `Graphics` context to pass to it. `frame.getGraphics()` returns `null`.

How can I find the size of a character? Can it be done without a `Graphics` instance? I don't want an instance of it anyway. I just want to know how big my characters are.

Comment: Your question is not clear, Can you provide more info with null part of code.

Comment: The font "size" will be based on the context of the rendering destination.  Generally you want to look at `Graphics#getFontMetrics` or some such related method.  If you don't have an available `Graphics` context, you could make a `BufferedImage` and use its.  The question then becomes one of, why do you want this information?

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you- I'll look into `BufferedImage`. FYI, I am using a `JFrame`/`JTextarea` to render a text based game, so I'll use this info for scaling the text and getting the dimensions of the window in units of characters.

Comment: @SamDev `JFrame#getGraphics()` is the method that returns `null`. I do this immediately after instantiating the `JFrame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JFrame#getFontMetrics` since one of JFrame's Superclass is `Component`.

If this does not work, you can also use `BufferedImage` to get a `Graphics` object:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

You can use the `image` object to get an instance of `Graphics`.

Comment: No I am talking about JFrame#getFontMetrics not Graphics#getFontMetrics

Comment: I have also added another way to get a Graphics object since you think my answer is wrong

Comment: While technically correct, based on what the OP is trying to do, it is probably not the best solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer the `JFrame#getFontMetrics` did work. I have submitted an edit to get rid of the rest of the answer because it should really go in a separate answer.

Comment: Rejected incase someone has a custom component that does not support getFontMetrics in some case

Comment: @Lolums I didn’t say it wouldn’t work, I just said that there was probably a better solution based on what you were trying to do

Answer (score 1):

> FYI, I am using a JFrame/JTextarea to render a text based game, so I'll use this info for scaling the text and getting the dimensions of the window in units of characters

It's probably not the best approach, it would be better to simply use [`JTextArea#setColumns`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setColumns-int-) and [`JTextArea#setRows`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setRows-int-) which will use the font based information to make determinations about it's preferred size automatically

You can then make use of the `LayoutManager` APIs and simply call `pack` on the `JFrame` which will pack the window around the contents, based on it's preferred size

This will also affect the preferred size of `JScrollPane`

Comment: Aha, I have tried using setRows and setCols but they unfortunately had no effect.

Comment: *"I have tried using setRows and setCols but they unfortunately had no effect"* Then something else is wrong, and that should be investigated & solved.

Comment: @Lolums I’ve used this technique a number of times before and it works very well, as Andrew says, if it’s not working, it’s likely because of something else you’re doing